# 'No executable code found at line *' within lambdas in Android Studio 3.5

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, kotlin

Whenever i try to debug lambdas within suspend functions i always get the "No executable code fount at line *". Sometimes this also occures within lambdas in regular functions.

Regular and suspend functions debugging works fine. Lambdas not:

[image: Example 1]

[image: Example 2]

Following some other answers i have already tried the following:

- removing .gradle, app/build and .idea and restarting
- invalidating caches and restarting
- cleaning project and resyncing gradle
- uninstalling the app from the device and reinstalling

**I am using AndroidStudio 3.5 and a debug build with minifyEnabled false**

```
    buildTypes {
        debug {
            minifyEnabled false
        }
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried adding keep class/package rules to your proguard file for all underlying code/libraries that are being used?

Comment: @Susheel Tickoo Thank you for taking the time to respond. This problem occurs in in a debug build with Proguard being disabled.

Answer (score 3):

I know it seems crazy but give it a try and Cut(<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>) the method and pasting somewhere else in the class.
This is definitely after cleaning the project.